# Plotting Points on Concentric Circles

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I have an array of items that I would like to place on concentric circles. See diagram.  I am having trouble with the math.

I can calculate the "steps" variable (each item is 40x40 so the steps are the circumference divided by the width plus margin). And I can calculate the points given the radius and the steps, but I don't know how to calculate the radius as a function of the current item index.

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var radius = functionOf(i)??;
    var steps = Math.floor((2*radius*Math.PI)/60);
    var x = Math.floor(0 + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * index / steps));
    var y = Math.floor(0 + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * index / steps));
    //draw item at x,y
}
```

Thoughts on how to calculate radius as a function of i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate radius for every item using sum of arithmetic progression (for equidistant circles number of items form that progression), but there is simpler and faster approach - change radius after circle filling (pseudocode)

```
var radius = 0;
var i = 0;
while (i < items.length) {
    var steps = Math.floor((2*radius*Math.PI)/60);
    for(var index = 0; index < steps; index++) {
        var x = Math.floor(0 + radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * index / steps));
        var y = Math.floor(0 + radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * index / steps));
        //draw item at x,y
        i++;
        if (i == items.length) 
           break;     
    }
    radius = radius + 60; //start next circle
}
```

About [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression):
for progression with the first item a0 and difference d the sum of first n members is

```
 S = n * (2 * a0 + d * (n - 1)) / 2
```

so to find what circle some index `S` belongs to, we have to solve quadratic inequality (find max integer x to fulfill the condition)

```
 x^2 * d + x * (2 * a0 - d) - 2 * S <= 0
```

checked solution in Delphi:

```
  function GetCircle(a0, d, i: Integer): Integer;
  var
    Discr: Double;
  begin
    Discr := (2 * a0 - d) * (2 * a0 - d) + 8 * i * d;
    if Discr < 0 then
      Exit(0);
    Result := Floor((d - 2 * a0 + Sqrt(Discr)) / (2 * d));
  end;
```

for case a0=1, d=6  (your picture differs a bit - progression is not exact) it gives

```
 i=0:       0
 i=1..7:    1
 i=8..20:   2
 i=21..39:  3
 and so on
```

This means:
0th item is at the circle with radius 0
3rd item at the circle with radius 1 * R
11th item at the circle with radius 2 * R
...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "using sum of arithmetic progression"?

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't depend on keep track of radius outside of the loop. I had thought of using a global radius variable similar to your solution, but in my application I can't be certain that the items will be processed in order or at all - so calculating radius needs to be independent for each item.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for (and a lot more complicated than I imagined).

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample image, an easy approach is to add 6 elements for every outer circle, so that we have the sequence: 1, 6, 12, 18...

Then the radius of each circle can be enlarged by a constant amount, bigger then the element size:

```
// center of the circles
var centerx = 350;
var centery = 350;
// start drawing the central (first) element
if ( items.length > 0 ) {
  // draw item at centerx, centery
}
var k = 1;
var i = 1;
while ( i < items.length ) {
    // number of elements on this circle
    var steps = k * 6;
    // angular distance between elements
    var angle_range = 2 * Math.PI / steps;
    // every circle is bigger then the previuos of the same amount
    var radius = k * 60;
    var j = 0;
    while ( j < steps  &&  i < items.length ) {
        var angle = j * angle_range;
        var x = Math.round(centerx + radius * Math.cos(angle));
        var y = Math.round(centery + radius * Math.sin(angle));
        //draw item at x,y

        i++;
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Circles</title>
  <link href="stile.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
  </canvas>
  <script>
  // dummy draw function
  function draw_item( itm, cntx, x, y) {
    cntx.fillStyle = "#0022FF";
    cntx.fillRect(x - 20, y - 20, 40, 40);
    cntx.font = "14px Arial";
    cntx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    cntx.fillText(itm, x - 7, y + 5);
  }

  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  // dummy array
  var items = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < 91; i++ ) {
    items.push(i);
  }

  // center of the circles
  var centerx = 350;
  var centery = 350;
  // start drawing the central (first) element
  if ( items.length > 0 ) {
    draw_item(items[0], ctx, centerx, centery);
  }
  var k = 1;
  var i = 1;
  while ( i < items.length ) {
      // number of elements on this circle
      var steps = k * 6;
      // angular distance between elements
      var angle_range = 2 * Math.PI / steps;
      // every circle is bigger then the previuos of the same amount
      var radius = k * 60;
      var j = 0;
      while ( j < steps  &&  i < items.length ) {
          var angle = j * angle_range;
          var x = Math.round(centerx + radius * Math.cos(angle));
          var y = Math.round(centery + radius * Math.sin(angle));
          //draw item at x,y
          draw_item(items[i], ctx, x, y);
          i++;
          j++;
      }
      k++;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```